# Cannot control servos through 32-servo-controller on Aurduino Duamilanove

Tags: servo, uart, arduino-duemilanove

I have servo (TowerPro sg90) connected to 32 servo controller ([this one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Version-32-Channel-Robot-Servo-Control-Board-Servo-Motor-Controller-PS2-Wireless-Control-USB-UART/32272674301.html)) through UART interface (RX-TX, GND-GND). 
Seller provide documentation how to connect and control my servos, but it isn't work.

Servo work if I connect it indirectly to Arduino. Controller indicate that it is working too (photo below - red led).

I already try different servos. Also try use provided software to control servos from pc through Mac/PC. But it's interface is unreadable for me. I tried different options but servos not responding.

Sketch code below (from sellers examples):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("#3P500T2000\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("#3P1500T2000\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.print("#3P2500T2000\r\n"); 
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("#3P1500T2000\r\n");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Photo of my connections:

[image: arduino-duamilanovo+32-servo-controller+servo]

Sorry if it post duplicate some, but I cannot google this problem.

Comment: Just as additional information. If there is a PS2 controller attached to the board, then the serial port seems turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one connection missing - the one that powers the servo and board.

At the moment your servo board is getting a small amount of power through the RX pin - **disconnect it immediately, you are damaging it**.

You need to provide +5V to the +5V terminal block, and also a suitable voltage (+5V should do) to the VCC on the terminal block.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and accept your answer as soon as possible. Can you provide some reference where I can read about it? Because I cannot figure it out by provided docs.

Comment: @rkyr The reference is simply that the servo and board need power (all servos and boards need power) yet you have not provided any. No docs are needed for that - it's just basic knowledge.